# YII2 i18n default language not work perfictly

Tags: yii2, internationalization

I used yii2 i18n many times and it works fine with me but in this project, I don't get the problem

in config file

```
'language' => 'ar-AR',
'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
```

and I've created a file in messages->ar-AR and. its works good but in empty data it shows `(belum diset)` in vendor yii2 i found it under id ( Indonesian ) language , i don't get the problem why it shows the Indonesian language .

Comment: Try checking your app's code for explicitly setting `Formatter::$nullDisplay` or `Formatter::$language` property somewhere.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I did, there is nothing weird in there I used `die(Yii::$app->language)` its ar-AR but it still not working

Comment: you will need to show more code examples for someone to be able to help

Comment: @ajmedway the i18n works fine, and I used it in the same app I translated from en to ar